# LMA count not being updated by CMA

Tags: isv, lma, cma

One of my clients purchased an additional license 4 days ago but it is still not available in the LMA. In the CMA correctly shows the license count, but I can't figure out how to get the LMA to update. I'm unable to do it manually as it's a Salesforce provisioned license. I've opened a case w/ Salesforce, but last time I did that it took them almost two weeks to answer me so I'm hoping there may be a fix or workaround someone here knows. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing this is something I cannot fix as they've escalated my case. =(